# TTY "Serial" Terminal over USB?

Tags: usb, terminal, serial

I have a few servers in a rack that like to drop their network connection, requiring a restart and/or handheld intervention. I purchased a Linksys NSLU2 and installed Debian on it in order to create a serial terminal. However, with USB-Serial converters running in the $30 range I'd really like to use USB (I have plenty of USB cables).

Is there a way to get Ubuntu Server to listen for "serial" terminals on a USB port? I doubt I'll coax the BIOS into talking to me over USB, but can I at least convince Ubuntu to do it?

Comment: Bull. Monoprice has USB->serial adapters for under $6 and I'm sure a ton of other places are in the ballpark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell mingetty or whatnot to connect to `ttyUSB<n>` in inittab.

Comment: I suppose I was assuming there would be some USB magic that needs to happen to get my terminal (a USB host) and a server (also a USB host) to talk to each other. I can try this though.

Comment: Wait, you're going to hook two USB ports directly to each other, without any intervening device? This won't work as both sides are expecting a USB slave, not another USB master.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking the problem would be. Can you recommend a device to throw in between that's less than $30? Otherwise I'll just stick with serial converters.

Comment: You might be able to get a USB-USB bridge cable, but those work as network devices, not serial devices.

Comment: mingetty? it does not set baud rate! agetty or mgetty work much better. (most getty clones work fine except for those designed exclusively for the console such as mgetty and fbgetty.)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management), which explains the basics of remote management.

Some servers have integrated out-of-band admin features, like HP iLO, IBM RSA and Dell DRAC, which could interest you as well.

Regarding the serial port solution, [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20191202021916/http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Serial/serial-console.html) explains how you can attach a dumb terminal to a linux host, using *getty.

I would not recommend some kind of serial over usb in that case, as it would limit the possibilities. No access to the bios, no access to the bootloader...